# Passing JQuery drag-and-drop changes to a file via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been using JQuery to be able to re-order table rows on a page, and then pass those changes to an external script via Ajax. The table rows are coming out in a specific order from a database that has a field called "Position" with a numeric field to determine what position it is in inside the table.

Overall it is functioning, but I'm not able to carry over the ID of the table row correctly to identify the change. Assuming the position of the table rows is 1, 2, 3 - if I do the first change and drag row 3 up a level, what I am getting out of the script is position[] = 1,3,2 (which is correct). However, if I then drag row 1 to the bottom it won't correctly update and seems to spit out random numbers. If I have more rows, the more dysfunctional it becomes. Code is below.

Ideally what I am looking for is to be able to say (for example): Table Row #1 is now Row #5 and run a loop through the previous Positions of 2-5 and make them 1-4.
I.E. Product ID #672 is now updated from Position 1 to Position 5. Product ID #897 was Position 5 and now is Position 4 etc.

Any help would be amazing! Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
<head>  
    <title> Example of Dynamic Drag and Drop table rows</title>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <div class="container">  
        <h3 class="text-center"> Example of Dynamic Drag and Drop table rows</h3>  
        <table class="table table-bordered">  
            <tr>  
                <th>#</th>  
                <th>Name</th>  
                <th>Definition</th>  
            </tr>  
            <tbody class="row_position">  
                <tr id="1">  
                    <td>761</td>  
                    <td>John Smith</td>  
                    <td>Student</td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr id="2">  
                    <td>990</td>  
                    <td>Steve Williams</td>  
                    <td>Student</td>  
                </tr>
                <tr id="3">  
                    <td>108</td>  
                    <td>Jenny Peterson</td>  
                    <td>Student</td>  
                </tr>
                <tr id="4">  
                    <td>12</td>  
                    <td>Suzy Cato</td>  
                    <td>Student</td>  
                </tr>
                <tr id="5">  
                    <td>885</td>  
                    <td>Bob Jones</td>  
                    <td>Student</td>  
                </tr>
            </tbody>  
        </table>  
    </div> <!-- container / end -->  
</body>  
  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $( ".row_position" ).sortable({  
        delay: 150,  
        stop: function() {  
            var selectedData = new Array();  
            $('.row_position>tr').each(function() {  
                selectedData.push($(this).attr("id"));  
            });  
            updateOrder(selectedData);  
        }  
    });  
  
    function updateOrder(data) {  
        $.ajax({  
            url:"AJAX SCRIPT HERE",  
            type:'post',  
            data:{position:data},  
            success:function(){  
                alert('your change successfully saved');  
            }  
        })  
    }  
</script>  
</html>
```

Passing the row values works OK, but I'm struggling with tying them back to the original ID of the row to effectively make the make the change. Again, my Ajax value is only giving position[] = 1,2,3 when I run a loop of all form items that come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, what you want received as result, I just added index to your function and AJAX script receive key-value object where key is `position`, value is `id`

```js
    $(function(){
        $( ".row_position" ).sortable({
            delay: 150,
            stop: function() {
                var selectedData = {};
                $('.row_position>tr').each(function(i) {
                    selectedData[i+1] = $(this).attr("id");
                });
                updateOrder(selectedData);
            }
        });

        function updateOrder(data) {
            console.log(data)
            // ...
        }
    })
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <h3 class="text-center"> Example of Dynamic Drag and Drop table rows</h3>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Definition</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody class="row_position">
        <tr id="1">
            <td>761</td>
            <td>John Smith</td>
            <td>Student</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2">
            <td>990</td>
            <td>Steve Williams</td>
            <td>Student</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="3">
            <td>108</td>
            <td>Jenny Peterson</td>
            <td>Student</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="4">
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Suzy Cato</td>
            <td>Student</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="5">
            <td>885</td>
            <td>Bob Jones</td>
            <td>Student</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works great. I spent so long trying to work it out :)